# Return Query Param from success Ajax - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to return data from `success` response?

Here is my code:

```js
$.ajax({
  async: 'true',
  url: 'https://exampleapi.com/product',
  type: 'GET',
  data: {page: idQuery},
  success:(response => {
    var idQuery = response.number;
  })
})
```

the goal is to put the variable in `response (idQuery)` to the data and it will become `query param`.
Should I using callback in success response? or any idea?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callback is an option, another option is setting the async flag `false`

```
var response = $.ajax({
                      async: false,
                      url: 'https://exampleapi.com/product',
                      type: 'GET',
                      data: {page: idQuery}
                     }).responseText;
var data = JSON.parse(response);
var idQuery = data.number;
```

Comment: I get new object from response, then I get idQuery, nice tips thank you. I try it @kiranvj

Answer (score 2):

That's correct that you would have to nest the callbacks if you wanted to do it that way. However, my understanding is that `jqXHR` will return a Promise-like object, which allows us to chain things together as such:

```
$.ajax({
  async: 'true',
  url: 'https://exampleapi.com/product',
  type: 'GET',
  data: {page: idQuery},
}).then(response => {
    const idQuery = response.number;
    return $.ajax(...) // your new call here
  }).then(...) // function when you're wanting to process results of second AJAX call
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a custom function that use the response as an input param

```
$.ajax({
  async: 'true',
  url: 'https://exampleapi.com/product',
  type: 'GET',
  data: {page: idQuery},
  success:(response => {
    var idQuery = response.number;
    doSomething(idQuery);
  })
})

function soSomething(idNumber){
...
}
```

i hope it works for you.